# cmake if test for GCC

Tags: gcc, cmake

What is the correct way to test if the compiler is GCC under Cmake?

I've seen both `if(CMAKE_COMPILER_IS_GNUCC)` and `if(CMAKE_COMPILER_IS_GNUXX)` but neither of those are defined when I run cmake. Just to be clear, I'm 100% sure I'm using GCC.

I just want to add compiler flags specific to GCC. Previously I just used an `else` clause after a check fro windows, but I want to be more generic now.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think I found the problem. Those properties aren't defined until after the `project` statement. Switching the ordering around and it appears to work.

Comment: The project() statement is used by CMake to determine what sort of project you're building (C, C++, Fortran) and so it needs it to be able to know what compiler to search for. project() and cmake_minimum_required() should usually be the very first things you do in you CMake script.